# Wait for graph - OS?

Tags: operating-system

> There are 6 processes each running on a different machine. The wait-for graph contains the following edges:
>
> ```
> P4 -> p5, p5 -> p6, p6 -> p7, p3 -> p4, p3 -> p2, p2 -> p7
> ```
>
> **Part 1**
>
> (a) Draw the graph
>
> (b) Does this represent a deadlock state?
>
> **Part 2**
>
> Process p3 times out. This removes the edges from p3 in the graph. At the same time p2 requests a resource held by p4.
>
> (a) Draw the new graph
>
> (b) Does this represent a deadlocked state?
>
> (c) Could there be a phantom edge? If so which one?
>
> **Part 3**
>
> Process p2 times out. This removes the edges from p2 in the graph. At the same time p7 requests a resource held by p4.
>
> (a) With a distributed algorithm, what probes could p7 receive in response to making its request?

Could some one help me with question part 2 and part 3 please. give me some hints how to proceed.

Comment: Funny, none of the easy-to-get-to fonts on my system can render the glyph for "". Maybe try again with `->` or `<-`?

Comment: sorry i guess my paste made that :( its p4"->"p5 and so on. Sorry about that!

Comment: well arnold, being new to the forum its kind of difficult maneuvering u know :)

Comment: I know it can be difficult, that's why I'm teaching :)

Comment: What have you tried doing? We are not here to answer your questions. You need to indicate some effort first.

Comment: I want to know if phanthom deadlock is what a phanthom edge causes ? if thats the case.. i saw a few examples and i think p2-> p7 should be the phanthom edge .. is that the way to go about this ?

Comment: part 2 , b i dont think there is a deadlock.. 

part 2 , c 

p2 waits for p4

p4 waits for p5

p5 waits for p6

p6 waits for p7

but p7 doesnt wait on anything
  
p2 also waits on p7

so the OS will put all process except p7 on wait

p7 can execute

because it doesnt have any dependencies
  
p7 finishes execution

now p6 gets the resource
9:29 PM 
then p5
  
then p4

it goes on reverse right



finally p4 gets

and that can be used by p2

Comment: for part 3 i am clueless what it is.. probes ? not very sure what probes means here ? or is it a typo and its problems ? no idea !

Comment: StackOverflow != HomeworkOverflow. Look at the user's questions. All of them are homework assignment questions!